# Is "intrum" a word?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

There is a company called Intrum, which was called Intrum Justitia from its founding in 1923 to a merger in 2017.
This strikes me as a clear attempt at making a name sound more prestigious by making it feel like Latin.
The name does not seem to make sense, although it is easy to imagine that something like "inside justice" was intended.
Perhaps *Intra Justitiam* would have felt less grandiose.

**Was *intrum* ever a real Latin word?**
Or are there perhaps other relevant words that might shed light on this one?
I have never seen the word, but that doesn't quite rule out the possibility of a rare or post-classical word, especially pertaining to legal language.
There are similar words like *inter* and *intra* and *intro*, and taking a leap and imagining a first and second declension adjective behind them might lead one to *intrum*.

There is always the chance that Intrum is the name of something that the company was named after and the resemblance to Latin is a coincidence, but I found nothing pointing in that direction.

(Just to be clear, I am in no way affiliated with the company. Nor do I think I could, given the quality of their titular Latin.)

Comment: For what it is worth, the company was [apparently](https://youtu.be/5hz0Z2sblVQ?t=2m35s) named in 1982 after a fictional company called "Intrum Art or something like that" in "some crime novel." Not kidding, that's how the person responsible tells it.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel You should just make that an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it doesn't appear in standard classical dictionaries, Du Cange, DMLBS, or Hoven's Dictionary of Renaissance Latin, it is most likely not a Latin word, though it is impossible to disprove it entirely.

If it was ever intended to reference Latin, it might have been an ill-formed adverb, as *Intus Justitia* is intelligible as "justice within [our company?]." It also occurs to me that *intrum* sounds like a rather lazy pronunciation of *interim* in some dialects.